# ADC Channel Selection on STM32L476RGT6

Tags: adc, stm32, arm, cortex-m4, cmsis

I am writing CMSIS based code for STM32L476RGT6(on a Nucleo board) to use the ADC. I have gone through the datasheet but I couldn't find a register to specify the channel for the ADC conversion. How do I do that on this microcontroller?

Comment: Use the ADC_SQRx registers, described in the ADC section of the reference manual.

Comment: There is another document called the Reference Manual. It contains all the information you need. You will notice that it is a significantly  longer than the DS :)